# need pointers to troubleshoot disabled input text controls jqm 1.4

Tags: jquery-mobile

Maybe somebody can provide ideas on how to address the following issue: input text controls on a jqm page are disabled in some browsers (latest chrome, ie 11) and work fine in mobile chrome, windows phone 7.1, safari on iphone. You can not click and type into those controls on some browsers so they appear disabled. select controls on the same page work fine. All other pages built similarly work fine.

Thank you

Comment: @Omar, thank you for your reply, it's hard to post the code since input controls are generated on the fly in code behind, but I just confirmed that it is related to jqm 1.4, when I switch back to 1.3.2 I have no problems. That's how generated controls look in browser:

Comment: <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br">
   <label for="ITEM8barcode" class="ui-input-text">Bar Code</label>
   <div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-b">
      <input name="ITEM8barcode" type="text" id="ITEM8barcode" class="dbcombo ui-input-text ui-body-b">
   </div>
</div>

Comment: I'd love to see how you create them dynamically. Are you calling `.textinput()` on the ones dynamically created?

Comment: They are created and inserted in ASP.Net on the server, I just added $('input').textinput(); to pagebeforeshow event but this didn't help, as I said it works in some browsers and works when I switch back to 1.3.2, also I use the same technique on other pages and it works fine.Thank you.